# Footnote numbering and alignment issue in \dictum KOMA-class scrbook

Tags: footnotes, alignment, scrbook

In the book that I am preparing, the chapters consist of lectures, given at specific dates. I'm using the `scrbook`-class, and am using the `\dictum` to note the date and the individual whose report is the source document. Regarding this `\dictum` there are two things that I would like to achieve: 1) adding footnotes and 2) aligning the `dictum`-text with to the right of the text area.

Re 1) I have managed to add the footnotes, but don't yet get how to make the number start with 1 instead of 0:

```
\setchapterpreamble[o]{%
\dictum[]{November 21st 1924 \newline Name\footnotemark[\thefootnote]{} of reporter}}
\addchap[tocentry={First lecture title \toclineinsert{4 January}},head={}]{First lecture}

\footnotetext[\thefootnote]{Why is this footnote numbered `0'?}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\footnote{Does the numbering still work?}, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
```

Re 2) How do I align the text of the `dictum` to the right?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\footnotemark[\thefootnote]{}` does not step the footnote counter. Remove the optional argument and you get the desired result.

To align the dictuum text with the right margin of the text area, redefine `\raggeddictumtext`:

```latex
\renewcommand*{\raggeddictumtext}{\raggedleft}
```

and replace `\newline` by `\\`:

```latex
\dictum[]{November 21st 1924 \\ Name\footnotemark{} of reporter}}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[headings=optiontotocandhead]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  linefill={},
]{tocline}{chapter}

\newcommand{\toclineinsert}[3][25mm]{%
    \dotfill
    \ #2\makebox[#1][l]{#3\dotfill}%
}

\renewcommand*{\raggeddictumtext}{\raggedleft}

\begin{document}
\setchapterpreamble[o]{%
  \dictum[]{November 21st 1924 \\ Name\footnotemark{} of reporter}}
\addchap
  [tocentry={First lecture title \toclineinsert{4 January}},head={}]
  {First lecture}
\footnotetext{Why is this footnote numbered `0'?}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]